# Fit UTF-8 string to bytelength 32

Tags: python, string, utf-8, arrays

I have a string `str` which may consist of UTF-8 characters. I want to write it to a file with the exact length of N bytes (may contain padding). So if `str` is longer than those N bytes it should be cut off so that it is shorter than N bytes and then padded to N bytes with `\0`bytes. Is there any good/fast method to do so in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to be careful, not to cut the byte stream off in middle of a multi-byte sequence. This seems to work:

```
def fixlen (s, length):
    bs = s.encode ('utf-8')
    bs = bs [:length]
    while True:
        try:
            bs.decode ('utf-8')
            break
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            bs = bs [:-1]
    return bs + b'\0' * (length - len (bs) )


s = 'LLegó cigüeña'
for length in range (0, 20):
    bs = fixlen (s, length)
    print (s, bs, bs.decode ('utf-8') )
```

Comment: wouldn't it be faster to preinit a `bytearray(length)` and then place the fitted string in there? (with `arr[:len(bs)] = bs`) Also, because I read it somewhere, with large strings `bs = bs[:-1]` could be `bs[:] = bs[:-1]` because that doesn't duplicate the array, right?